# Getting the current context ID in a Apache-hosted Delphi-created ISAPI dll

Tags: multithreading, apache, delphi, soap, indy

I have a thread-safe class that I use to get the correct TADOConnection for any given thread.  This works great in my executables.  It boils down to the following:

```
function ConnectionForCurrentThread () : TADOConnection;
var
  thread : TThread;
begin
  thread := TThread.CurrentThread;
  result := adoConnectionFactory.ConnectionForID(thread.Handle);
end;
```

Where the adoConnectionFactory ends up handling a critical section to either return an existing ADO connection that's stored in a list, or making a new one if one isn't already created for that thread handle.  Later, I test them to free them with a

```
if Windows.GetExitCodeThread(threadID, res) then begin
  if res <> Windows.STILL_ACTIVE then begin
    TADOConnection(connections.Objects[i]).Free;
    connections.Delete(i);
  end;
end else begin
  TADOConnection(connections.Objects[i]).Free;
  connections.Delete(i);
end;
```

This all seems to be working well.  Where it's falling over is when used in a SOAP webservice ISAPI dll, hosted by Apache.  The Thread.Handle ends up being the same for two simultaneous calls to the web service, so they attempt to share the same ADO Connection, which will occasionally throw exceptions due to the different threads fiddling with the same connection.

My question is, what can I use instead of the CurrentThread.handle?  I'd really like this to be self-contained in this function call, so that if I recognize it's in web service dll mode, I would instead do something like:

```
function ConnectionForCurrentThread () : TADOConnection;
var
  thread : TThread;
  ct : TContextThing;
  id : integer;
begin
  if WebServiceMode then begin
    ct := TContextThing.CurrentContext;
    id := ct.ContextID;
  end else begin
    thread := TThread.CurrentThread;
    id := thread.Handle;
  end;
  result := adoConnectionFactory.ConnectionForID(id);
end;
```

But I'm not too sure what that ContextThing might be.  Any suggestions? And then on the flip side, how to see that a given context ID is no longer active so that its ADOConnection can be closed.

This is using Delphi XE and the SOAP server application (So, WebBroker, TWebModule, all that jazz).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For an ISAPI application, the following should work (assuming Apache fills in the ISAPI ECB correctly with a unique connection ID).

```
uses
  Web.WebCntxt,
  Web.Win.IsapiHttp;

if WebServiceMode then
  id := TIsapiRequest(WebContext.Request).ECB^.ConnID
else
  ...
```

Comment: Is the default Delphi XE SOAP server application supposed to instantiate WebContext?  Because it's nil, and looks like something that shouldn't be created on the fly.

Comment: Yes, if it's an ISAPI application it should initialize WebContext automatically.

Comment: Hmmm, in that case, I'm not too sure why it's not created at that point.  The application is pretty much
`CoInitFlags := COINIT_MULTITHREADED; 
Application.Initialize;
Application.MaxConnections := 255;
NumberOfThreads := 255;
Application.WebModuleClass := WebModuleClass;
Application.Run;`

Sorry, I need to look up how to format code in a comment.  But, the core functions aren't that different from a new, empty SOAP Server Application, but the WebContext object's nil.

Comment: Is your HttpExtensionProc called by Apache?

Comment: Took a while to verify - but yes.  A call to a particular web service function is going through ISAPIThreadPool.HttpExtensionProc , to ISAPIApp.HttpExtensionProc, then to my function call.

Comment: So it looks like the call I want is GetSOAPWebModule.Request, rather than WebContext.Request.  Now I just need to get the disconnect event, to free the ADO connection at the end of its lifecycle.